# How to share image downloaded from flutter

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, flutter

I use flutter to save a widget as an image in flutter. I have no problem with downloading the image but im having troubke with sharing the image. Is there a way i way share the downlaoded image without leaving the application?

Here's my present code

```
   onPressed: () async {
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      screenshotController.capture(pixelRatio: 1.5);
      screenshotController.capture().then((File image) async {
        await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(image.readAsBytesSync());

        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text("Image Saved to Gallery"),
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          ),
        );
      }).catchError((onError) {
//                                    print(onError);
      });
    } else {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the image as any other file.

If you do not intend to use a server between the two users, its a bit tricky because one of them must act as one, but if you will use a server, i suggest you to follow this post:

https://dev.to/carminezacc/advanced-flutter-networking-part-1-uploading-a-file-to-a-rest-api-from-flutter-using-a-multi-part-form-data-post-request-2ekm

It's pretty recent and will help you with the app code and even with a server sample writen in nodejs. The next parts of the post teach you to do what you want.

Comment: Im not sure you understood the question. There are packages like https://pub.dev/packages/share which allow sharing of text.

Comment: I want to share an image the same way

Comment: You can't. Try to do the same from whatsapp or any other app, they will open the requested app. There are ways to share information between apps, but image involves access to the other app folders and it is not allowed.

Comment: No. The images are from my app. I have permission to access them. i just need to share them.
For example, i achieved this in Java using an intent and it was simple. flutter is a little tricky

Comment: I see. Sorry for the mistake. You need to open the image inside flutter like any other file and not an image. I'll Update my answer.